# Error: Truffle is currently using solc 0.5.8,

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration, truffle-contract, truffle-deployment

I run migrate in the terminal, but it shows

> Error: Truffle is currently using solc 0.5.8, but one or more of your contracts specify "pragma solidity ^0.4.27".
>
> Please update your truffle config or pragma statement(s).

[image]

When I follow the error and update config it doesn't work.
What should I do? Thanks.

Comment: The error is self explanatory.. your contracts are based on an earlier version of solidity. I would advise downgrading your solc compiler or setting it a different version ,

Comment: there is no compiler version satisfying `^0.4.27` the latest `0.4.x` compiler version is `0.4.26` and, btw, if you're using Ubuntu the config file should be named `truffle.js`

Answer (score 2):

Inside of the truffle-config.js you can update the solc version like so:

```
compilers: {
  solc: {
    version: "^0.8.0"
  }
}
```

Here is a full example:

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "*" // Match any network id
    }
  },
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "^0.8.0"
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: i put the right version in solc, but i'm still getting the same error

Answer (score 0):

On MacOS, change compiler settings in `truffle-config.js`. Also, make sure the pragma versions in your contracts are the same as in your config settings as you won't be able to run `truffle compile` successfully otherwise.